# PFsense not working with second subnet

Tags: routing, pfsense

192.168.1.5 PC can go online
192.168.2.5 PC can not go online but can ping 192.168.1.1

When PF Sense is rebooted 192.168.2.5 can ping an internet address briefly but then stops once PF Sense is fully loaded.

Any idea what could be causing this?

I do have a static route on PF Sense point the 192.168.2.1 network to the router

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're either missing a firewall rule on the second interface to allow Internet access, or your NAT is missing the other subnet if you're using manual outbound NAT.

Comment: automatic NAT is turned on and the second subnet is detected. Also I allowed everything through the firewall for testing and made no difference. I'm sure the issue is NAT or firewall related but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Ended up scrapping the server, might as well give you the points for trying to answer.